# Java: Why isn't my BufferedReader reading the next line of my code?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline

// Here is my code. What it should do: read in a .txt file, line by line. Take each line (which has its info separated by commas), split it, take each data and create an ObjectName2 object instance. Use addData method to add the ObjectName2 to ObjectName1. Problem: reads first line fine, adds it to ObjectName1. Reads same line, encounters duplicate line, throws exception. Keeps reading first line. It won't ever move on to the second line. From what I see with my code, it should work fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This code is all in another class, say ObjectName3.

EDIT: what happens is it prints out to the console that it found a duplicate line, say lineName. Then it prints out to the console again: Duplicate line found, lineName. Then again, and again, and again. It keeps going on forever. It's infinite. It never gets past that first line. Just keeps saying "Duplicate line: lineName".

```
public ObjectName1 load() {

    ObjectName1 list = new ObjectName1();
    BufferedReader fileIn;
    String inputLine;
    try {
        fileIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileName));
        inputLine = fileIn.readLine(); // read in first line
        while (inputLine != null) {
            String[] listOfData = inputLine.split(",");
            String data1= listOfData[0];
            String data2= listOfData[1];
            String data3= listOfData[2];
            int data4= Integer.parseInt(listOfData[3]);
            int data5= Integer.parseInt(listOfData[4]);
            ObjectName2 data= new ObjectName2(data1, data2, data3, data4, data5);
            list.addData(data); // throws exception if duplicate data encountered
            inputLine = fileIn.readLine(); // read in next line?
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { // happens if we try to add duplicate data
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        boolean lineAfterException = true;;
        while (inputLine != null) {
            if (lineAfterException) {
                inputLine = fileIn.readLine();
                lineAfterException = false;
            }
            String[] listOfData = inputLine.split(",");
            String data1 = listOfData [0];
            String data2 = listOfData [1];
            String data3 = listOfData [2];
            int data4 = Integer.parseInt(listOfData [3]);
            int data5 = Integer.parseInt(listOfData [4]);
            ObjectName2 data= new ObjectName2 (data1, data2, data3, data4, data5);
            list.addData(data)
            inputLine = fileIn.readLine();
        }
    }
    fileIn.close();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: add your method addData from ObjecName1 class.

Comment: No. Ok so what happens is it prints out to the console that it found a duplicate line, say: lineName. Then it prints out to the console again: Duplicate line found, lineName. Then again, and again, and again. It keeps going on forever. It's infinite. It never gets past that first line.

Answer (score 0):

**I think it is actually reading it.**

you can validate this adding this line:

System.out.println(inputLine);

**after this one:**

inputLine = fileIn.readLine();

---

inputLine = fileIn.readLine();

System.out.println(inputLine);

I think your problem is when you compare the lines, i mean, this line:
list.addData(data); **// throws exception if duplicate data encountered**

I think that would be helpfull if you post how you are comparing the lines, i mean, if you are comparing correctly the content of the lines instead the pointer to an object in memory